# Parse everything inside <form></form> using Android from HTML code?

Tags: java, android

Well, the question is pretty clear. I wanna grab the form-element and everything inside it from a web site and then load it to my own WebView. I have looked around, but since I'm quite new to parsing overall, I really need help. I've looking at some solutions; but I don't get it. Help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance and tell me if my question is unclear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you search for Java open source HTML parsers, you will find several options, such as [this list](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers).